# How to get an array of data in google sheets based on date in column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to pull sub-section of data from one google sheet to another each day. The pull is conditional based on date which is why I am struggling.

Context - I have 'Workbook 1' that logs price data each day for different NBA teams. The data is captured and added to the bottom of the table each day (so the most current price data is at the bottom). It is date-stamped in column K with =today().. header is "Pull Date".

I have a separate workbook we'll call 'Workbook 2' for the NBA in which I would like to include that SAME price data from Workbook 1, but only for a trailing 15 days (to keep it more agile). To accomplish this, I'd like to have the script incrementally add yesterday's values each morning from 'Workbook 1' to 'Workbook 2' (and for now I will be manually deleting any rows older than 15 days).

Purpose - I've build a report on the table in Workbook 2 with trailing two-week analysis because the Workbook 1 file is simply too big (goes back several months).

Issue - I have some old code from an unrelated workbook where I pull data from one sheet to another but it's not conditional based on pull-date. For this script, I'd like my 'Workbook 2' workbook to request data from 'Workbook 1' and add it to the bottom of sheet 1 on 'Workbook 2' but ONLY for rows containing yesterday's date ( or =today()-1). The amount of rows containing yesterday's date is dynamic and shrinking over time, so I don't have the same amount of rows to move today as I did last week, for ex.

My array is 15 columns wide but the row count will change daily. Below is my starting point:

```
function runOne() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Workbook 1 sheet id');
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName('sheet 1');
  ???
```

I have no idea how to conditionally pull yesterday's data AND make the row count dynamic. After I've gotten the proper values, I would need to paste it on the bottom of tab titled "sheet 1" in the 'Workbook 2'.

I have very little experience with scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried to clarify above as much as possible but let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: Can your share a link to an example spreadsheet?

Comment: Sure, [here you go](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11LvCnHx9x5PP9eGZpgttXyMP6diXeZhxOEwiHcDvYF4/edit#gid=0). This is a much smaller sample (only 156 rows instead of 18,000) but the concept and format are the same. I've sorted by pull date.

This is workbook 1 (master data workbook) but both workbooks 1 & 2 are the same format. Workbook 2 would call the data from workbook 1.

Comment: Have you seen the Sheets `query` function? You could use it on another sheet in the first workbook to filter the source data. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

Comment: Share a sample copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: @cooper I shared in my comment above. Click the link. (Forgot to tag you).

Comment: That needs to be a public link.

Comment: @Cooper sorry, [here's the public link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQn7btfy3mSduyUFqeJSeI-r1LjzXiZ6iT4_OAymo0mh0HmA90yXgSUlgj2ht7eb9bUoqLuXxbu699L/pubhtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your date stamp is in column 11 (K)
- you want to run the script every day automatically (on time trigger)
- you want to add to your workbook 2 sheet 1 entries from workbook 1 sheet 1 with the timestamp of yesterday

### This is how you can implement it

- Write a code that calculates the date from yesterday and compares it against the timestamps in column K

```
function runOne() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Workbook 1 spreadsheet id');
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName('sheet 1');
  var ss2=var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Workbook 2 spreadsheet id');
  var tsh2=ss2.getSheetByName('sheet 1');
  var lastRow=tsh.getLastRow();
  var timestamps=tsh.getRange(1,11,lastRow,1).getValues();
  var yesterdayMs=new Date().getTime()-24*60*60*1000;  //get the date from yesterday in ms
  var yesterdayDate=new Date(yesterdayMs);   // get the date from yesterday
  for(var i=lastRow;i>1;i--){              // get the last row from yesterday
    if(new Date(timestamps[i-1][0]).getDay()==yesterdayDate.getDay()){
      var lastRowYesterday=i;
      break;
    }
  }
  for(var j=lastRowYesterday-1;j>1;j--){  // get the first row from yesterday
    if(new Date(timestamps[j-1][0]).getDay()!=yesterdayDate.getDay()){
      var firstRowYesterday=j+1;
      break;
    }
  }
  var rowNumber=lastRowYesterday-firstRowYesterday+1;
  var columnNumber=tsh.getLastColumn();
  var toCopy=tsh.getRange(firstRowYesterday,1,rowNumber,columnNumber).getValues(); //values from yesterday
  var lastRow2=tsh2.getLastRow();
  tsh2.getRange(lastRow2+1,1,rowNumber,columnNumber).setValues(toCopy);  //append to workbook 2
}
```

- Bind to the function to an [installable Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), selecting the time of the day to run as desired.

[image]

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka thanks for the comment and sorry I'm just getting a chance to run it a couple days later.. I'm getting a syntax error in row 4. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka I tweaked the script to fix the error but for some reason it's pulling rows from 12/7, not yesterday. *updated script lines 4 & 5: `var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Workbook 2 spreadsheet id');
  var tsh2=ss2.getSheetByName('sheet 1');`

Comment: I assume that the syntax error comes from the fact that you did not replace 'Workbook 2 spreadsheet id' through the real ID of your second workbook correctly. If 'sheet 1' is not the name of your sheet of interest in workbook 2 - please replace the name accordingly. Mind the case sensitivity! E.g. 'sheet 1' is not the same like 'Sheet 1' which is not the same like 'Sheet1'.

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka - I ran it again this morning and it's working. Thanks so much for the help my friend you're a life saver! I've marked your comment as the answer.

Comment: one last question @ziganotschka. The code worked in my sample workbooks, but when I carry it over to the actual workbooks it's pasting the date field in a different format. It's grabbing the correct data (for yesterday), but the date after pasting shows as "1/4/2020 23:00:00". Any ideas how I could fix this? I tried reformatting the entire column but no luck. Again, it's grabbing the correct data (1/5/2020 in original workbook) but pasting as 1/4/2020 23:00:00.

Comment: Is the date containing column in your actual workbook 1 formatted as date?

Comment: It is. I built a new workbook and the data transfer worked fine [again] so I'm thinking there was something wrong with that specific version of Workbook 1. Thanks - you've been very patient with my inexperience here..One last question if you don't mind.. I was hoping to duplicate this code in the script editor of workbook 2 and pull from a _third_ workbook, then deposit starting in column P of sheet 1 (same array size). It looks like the edit would be in lines 22-26 of the code but I can't figure it out. Any idea how I might execute?

Comment: You need to edit the workbook id, the sheet name (if necessary) and the range. To adapt the range, you have to change the column NUMBER (16 for "P") and if necessary the range size - see here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer) It is important that the original and destination ranges have the same dimensions.

Comment: I've updated the ID's but reformatting the ranges is a little over my head. Here's what I have but while the code is running without any bugs, it's not 'executing' anything. You've been very helpful, so I don't want to keep coming to you with questions. I'll likely add this as a new post unless there's an obvious tweak that I'm missing.. `var lastRow2=tsh2.getRange(tsh2.getLastRow()+3,16,610,15);
  lastRow2.setValues(toCopy);`

Comment: When you use the method `setValues` it is very important that the destination range has the same dimensions like the `toCopy` range. I agree with you that for visibility reasons it is easier if you create a new post and implement your complete (relevant) code into it.